# Example of using default-graph-uri query parameter in MarkLogic Rest API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

According to the [document here](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/graphs/sparql), it is possible to use named graph as a query parameter. However, I am having problem getting it to work. I am wondering if anyone has a working example using one or more named graphs for the query. I have tried the following without success,

```
http://localhost:9001/v1/graphs/sparql?default-graph-uri="<http://www.my.org/concept>"&query=select * where {?s ?p ?o FILTER ( ?s = <http://www.my.org/concept/concept_data%23WXYX_00000> ) }
```

The request returns empty. Without the default-graph-uri parameter, the request returns data. The following query returns data in the query console as well as using the REST api:

```
select * 
FROM <http://www.my.org/concept>
where 
{?s ?p ?o 
 FILTER ( ?s = <http://www.my.org/concept/concept_data#WXYZ_00000> )}
```

This test uses only one named graph but I would like to be able to use multiple default graphs.

I tried named-graph-uri parameter as well without success.

Comment: Can you tell more about how you ingested your data, and what kind of permissions are applied to it?

Comment: How do you send the request? Can you post a repro using CURL or HTTPie? Can you log the actual values received on the server for the parameters? Have you tried without the `<` and `>` for the URI? (and maybe without `"` as well)

Comment: @Florent Georges, withougt the <, >, and " appears to work. I did not think of that combination. Thanks. Now, the problem is how to specify multiple graphs. I tried + and ; between graphs without success. Any idea? I have been testing with `Postman`.

Comment: Figured it out. Just specifying the same parameter multiple times.

Comment: @AlexW, if you could add your solution as an answer and accept it, that would help others who run into this (and make it clear that this question doesn't need additional help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<`, `>` and `"` from the parameter value, just use the, well, URI.

Use the parameter several times to provide several values.

Comment: Sounds OK like that ;-)

Comment: The key for me to understand this was "Use the parameter several times".

I found this works for sem:sparql queries, too, ie, 

sem:sparql($query,(),("default-graph=graph1","default-graph=graph2"))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might be wrong with the named-graph-uri parameter..

But.. Have you simply tried the query defining the graph in the from clause?  This is also valid via t rest endpoint instead of the parameter.

Comment: using the `FROM` clause works as stated in my question. We want to avoid re-constructing the query string to query a different set of graphs.

Comment: Your statement said that you used the FROM clause in the query console and did not specifically state it about the rest request. Hence the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, okay. I updated my question to make that clear. Thanks.